# extjs grid dnd plugin doesnt create value

Tags: api, extjs, extjs4, store, drag-and-drop

I copy this example, and define my model and store. 
http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html

```
          proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            api:{
                create: '/msDx2PlaylistAudio/create',
                update: '/msDx2PlaylistAudio/create',
                destroy:'/msDx2PlaylistAudio/delete'
            },

            url:'/msDx2Playlist/loadData',

            reader:{
                type:'json',
                root:'data'
            }
```

as you can see i will set api create, update  and destroy action. But when i drag and drop my grid rows my stores do only destroy and load action. I do not understand why stores doesnt execute any create... In another app where i have one grid autosync works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[autoSync](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-autoSync) is false by default, set it to true.

var secondGridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'DataObject'
**autoSync:true**
});

Comment: I set it to true. That doesnt help. As I said before: destroy and load  work fine, but create ignoring...

Answer (score 0):

With 4.1.1 at least, the problem is that the record you are dragging has its `phantom` set to false. The code that handles the drop is shown below, and you will see that there's nothing to set the dropped records `phantom` flag to true before it is inserted to the new store.

This appears to be a bug.

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.ViewDropZone', {
    extend: 'Ext.view.DropZone',

    handleNodeDrop : function(data, record, position) {
        var view = this.view,
            store = view.getStore(),
            index, records, i, len;

        // If the copy flag is set, create a copy of the models
        if (data.copy) {
            records = data.records;
            data.records = [];
            for (i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
                data.records.push(records[i].copy());
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * Remove from the source store. We do this regardless of whether the store
             * is the same bacsue the store currently doesn't handle moving records
             * within the store. In the future it should be possible to do this.
             * Here was pass the isMove parameter if we're moving to the same view.
             */
            data.view.store.remove(data.records, data.view === view);
        }

        index = store.indexOf(record);

        // 'after', or undefined (meaning a drop at index -1 on an empty View)...
        if (position !== 'before') {
            index++;
        }
        store.insert(index, data.records);
        view.getSelectionModel().select(data.records);
    }
});
```